# Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR) v2.0.50727 with HRESULT 0x80131522

Tags: sql

I am getting the error

Msg 6512, Level 16, State 27, Line 6
Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR) v2.0.50727 with HRESULT 0x80131522. You need to restart SQL Server to use CLR integration features.

i am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Edition with windows 7. This error occur while creating the stored procedure. inside this stored procedure i am inserting some temp data in a variable table which has only a single column with HIERARCHYID as a the datatype

after some google i come to know that this is something related to CLR so i have enabled the clr in sql server

after that if i check "select * from dm_clr_properties" this says state as "CLR initialization permanently failed"

can anyone please help

Answer (score 3):

SQLCLR initialization failed due to which you are not able to perform the insert. HierarchyID data type uses CLR objects. Have you tried repairing the .NET framework on the machine>

Comment: The problem is caused by updating the .NET Framework (to say, Service Pack 2) after SQL Server is installed. Repairing the .NET Framework restores the functionality.

Comment: I had to repair (I used the DISM command to disable, rebooted, then used the DISM command to enable) and then restart SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You should try running the following in the database that is giving you this problem:

```
select * from sys.assemblies        --This is important to check.
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties --This is important to check.
```

If nothing is returned by *sys.assemblies*, then you have a problem.
If "*state*", from sys.drm_clr_properties, says something other than "*CLR is initialized*", then you have a problem.

You will need to reinstall the .net framework or try repairing it using this tool:
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135
Note: Our DBA wasn't able to complete the repair because it required restarting the server which is a big deal for our production envrionment.